# SQLException, ResultSet closed but I can figure out why

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, resultset, sqlexception

I'm having a problem with java.sql.ResultSet, I have a java.sql.PreparedStatement on which I run executeQuery() to return a ResultSet yet when I try to get the results from the query I'm getting an Exception thrown:

> Exception: java.sql.SQLException  Message: Operation not allowed after
>   ResultSet closed.

From searching online it looks like a ResultSet can end up being closed for a few reason:

1. The PreparedStatement object that generated it is closed.
2. The PreparedStatement object that generated it is re-executed.
3. The PreparedStatement object that generated it is used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.
4. Closing the Connection which was used to generate the PreparedStatement.

I checked my code and do none of those things.  Below is a snippet of the code that causes the problem:

```
PreparedStatement psAccountPartyIdByEmail = null;
....
try {
    String [] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        String email = nextLine[0];
        .....
        try {
            if (psAccountPartyIdByEmail == null) {
                psAccountPartyIdByEmail = session.connection().prepareStatement(SQL_GET_ACCOUNTPARTYID_BY_EMAILADDRESS);
            }

            psAccountPartyIdByEmail.setString(1, email);
            ResultSet partyIds = psAccountPartyIdByEmail.executeQuery();

            while (partyIds.next()) {
               String partyId = partyIds.getString(1);
                .....
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, "Encountered SQLException while running group service.", MODULE);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Debug.logError(e, "Problem reading line in file", MODULE);
}
```

The Exception is thrown when trying to execute: `while (partyIds.next()) {`

Like I stated I never close the connection or statement and as you can see I don't reuse the statement prior to trying to view my result.

Thanks for he help...

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix this problem but you can/should move

```
if (psAccountPartyIdByEmail == null) {
            psAccountPartyIdByEmail = session.connection().prepareStatement(SQL_GET_ACCOUNTPARTYID_BY_EMAILADDRESS);
        }
```

outside of the while loop.
Also, close the ResultSet after you've processed the rows.
Then, when you're all done close your statement and connection.

Comment: I have tried both your recommendations and it has made no difference.  Out of curiosity why would you move the above code outside the loop and why do you think that would make a difference.

Comment: I was hoping the closing of the ResultSet would do the trick.  As to moving the PS creation, there's no reason to keep checking for it in the loop; unless maybe it's likely that there's no reader.nextLine() in which case the PS will be created for no reason.

Comment: What database and driver are you using?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver and mySQL

Comment: To be more specific mysql-connector-java-5.1.13 and mySQL 5.5

Comment: As a test can you try to run some queries serially?  That is, something like: open connection, create PS, execute query, look in RS, close RS, close PS, close connection.  Then repeat and see what happens the second time thru.